# Connect device straight to VM (Passthrough?)

Tags: windows-7, macos, drivers, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I've a Windows 7 VM on my VMWare Fusion 5.0.1 running on OSX 10.8.2.
I want to connect it a tablet (Smart Pad 810c) that OSX doesn't recognize at all (it's not listed either in USB system configuration).
I know it can be recognized by Win7, but I don't know how to connect it skipping OSX.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Although unlikely, it doesn't hurt to check whether Mac OS X sees the connected device, this is also useful if you want to get the device and vendor IDs of the device.

*Apple Menu > About This Mac > System Report > Hardware > USB*

Do you see the tablet listed among other USB devices connected to your Mac? If yes, you should be able to give the VMWare guest access to the device.

**Giving Windows 7 VM direct access to USB devices**

1. Shutdown Windows 7
2. If Virtual Machine Library is not already showing go to: *VMware Fusion Menu > Window > Virtual Machine Library*
3. Hold down Option key and right click on the Windows 7 VM
4. Click on Open Config File in Editor
5. Backup a copy of the .vmx file.
6. Scroll down to bottom and add the following line:

   `usb.generic.allowHID = "TRUE"`
7. Save .vmx file and close editor

When you start the Windown 7 VM, you will be able to connect directly.

*VMWare Menu > Virtual Machine > USB & Bluetooth >*

Once you connect a device to Windows it can only be accessed exclusively by Windows until it is disconnected or the guest OS is shutdown.

For more information see VMWare KB articles: 
[Connecting a second mouse or keyboard directly to a ...](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1033435)
and
[Automatically connecting USB devices at virtual machine power on](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1648)